# Get entire array of objects after mapping duplicates by a deep nested key

Tags: javascript

I have a huge nested array of objects and I want to filter and remove the duplicates, defined by the deep nested key `uniqueId`. With the following mapping I only get the values for the key `uniqueId`. But I need the entire array of objects `m`.

**JS**

```
var medis = [...new Map(m.map( o => [o['drugs'][0]['ingredient'].uniqueId, o['drugs'][0]['ingredient'].uniqueId])).values()];
```

**Questions:**

1. How do I get the filtered array `m`?
2. Is it possible within the mapping to keep only the last duplicate?

Thank you for your hints

Comment: You are creating a map where both the key and the value are the uniqueId, did you mean to create a map where the key is the uniqueId and the value is the object instead? Consider taking a look at libraries like lodash and their source code for ways to implement uniqBy efficiently (you are not very far off! :)).

Comment: Oh yes you're right! It was a mistake!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would rather use a [Set](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) to store the unique ids. You could use [Reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) instead of map to do your filter. There you would validate if the set contains the object key in order to add to the accumulator array:

```
const uniqueKeys = new Set()

const medis = m.reduce((uniqueArray, o) => {
  const key = o['drugs'][0]['ingredient'].uniqueId
  if(uniqueKeys.has(key)) return uniqueArray
  uniqueKeys.add(key)
  uniqueArray.push(o)
  return uniqueArray
},[])
```

Note: If you want to store to the array each last object duplicated instead you can use [ReduceRight](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduceRight) instead.

Comment: I think this keeps the first, not the last, of the duplicates

Comment: @ChrisLear, yes that's correct. I was unsure about if that's what he wanted as second question. if you use reduceRight you would store the last ones rather than the first ones. I added to the answer. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

It's a bit tricky to know exactly what you want because you don't provide sample data, but here's something that might work. Instead of reducing the array in place, I'm making a new map `n`.

```js
//var medis = [...new Map(m.map( o => [o['drugs'][0]['ingredient'].uniqueId, o['drugs'][0]['ingredient'].uniqueId])).values()];


let m = [

{'drugs':[
  {'ingredient': {
    'name':'first',
    'uniqId':1
  }}
]},
{'drugs':[
  {'ingredient': {
    'name':'second',
    'uniqId':2
  }}
]},
{'drugs':[
  {'ingredient': {
    'name':'first-overwritten',
    'uniqId':1
  }}
]},

]


let n = new Map();
m.map(o=>{n[o['drugs'][0]['ingredient'].uniqId]=o});
console.log(n);
```